# Setting up dual monitors

Tags: 10.10, xorg, ati, resolution, multiple-monitors

Just installed a fresh copy of Maverick, and went from my two monitors working perfectly to broken in seconds.

As usual I configured the monitors in the display applet, this worked fine. I also hit Make Default which gave me no problems. I then restarted and the monitors had gone back to Mirror Screen. I changed them back again and hit Make Default which gave me a message about setting the Virtual Desktop resolution. After this any changes I make to the monitors give me the message "Please log out and back in again" - I've tried that and restarting but still cannot configure the monitor resolutions.

Any ideas on how I can revert this? Some searching indicates the problem's with xorg but I've no idea where to go further than this.

Here's the relevant `lspci` output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series]
```

I tried extending the desktop using ATI's Catalyst tool but this still mirrored the screens. Does this mean the drivers aren't being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your edits:

you disabled the ATI drivers and it works automatically.

Problem solved, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with setting up my dual monitors as well. I had to go into my BIOS and set my default video adapter from Auto to PCI x16.